# How can I optimise an nested select?

Tags: sql, openedge

My use-case is to retrieve invoices for a customer and a format code for each invoice which is found by a join to a `customer_list` table which a join to a generalised code table to work out the format code.

A simplified version of my query follows, which is working fine, yet the subquery would return around 5k of rows, I have to wonder how this could be optimised so the sub-query did not contain as many rows.

```
select i.invoice_number,
       f.format_code
  from invoices i
  left join (
    select gc.code_1 as format_code,
           ls.account
      from gen_codes gc,
           customer_list ls
     where gc.code_name = 'invoice-format'
       and gc.code_1 <> ''
       and ls.list_type = gc.code_value
  ) f on account = i.account
      or account = i.billing_account
where i.account = :accountNumber
```

**NOTE**: Not all invoices have a format code, which is fine and why I am performing a left join.

**UPDATE**: A similar query without using an inner select would be of the following form:

```
select i.invoice_number,
       f.code_1 as format_code
  from invoices i
  left join customer_list ls on
    (account = i.account or account = i.billing_account) and ls.list_type in (
           select code_value
             from gen_codes
            where code_name = 'invoice-format'
              and code_1 <> ''
        )
  left join gen_codes f on code_value = ls.list_type
                       and code_name = 'invoice-format'
                       and code_1 <> ''
```

I have a feeling this latter version may be more efficient as there are only two dozen records in `gen_codes` with the matched query while `customer_list` contains ~ half a million records with ~5k matching in the first version.

Comment: To help me better understand inner select statements, how do SQL engines interpret this? Do they execute the inner select before the outer select statement? And if so this result is reused for the remainder of the select so it has only been executed once?

Answer (score 0):

I would write it as follows:

Get all the invoices corresponding to an account or billing account (using JOIN and ON clauses) and get only those gen_codes associated with the list_types of the account matched (using LEFT JOIN) whose code_name is 'invoice-format' and gc.code_1 is not empty.

```
SELECT 
    i.invoice_number,
    gc.code_1 as format_code
FROM 
    invoices i
    JOIN customer_list ls
    ON 
        (i.billing_account = ls.account OR i.account = ls.account) AND 
        i.account = :accountNumber
    LEFT JOIN gen_codes gc
    ON 
        ls.list_type = gc.code_value AND 
        gc.code_name = 'invoice-format' AND 
        gc.code_1 != ''
```

This will prune the customer_list records that doesn't match the accountNumber input upfront, compared to the subquery in your question.

Comment: A customer might not have a `gen_codes` entry for the list type which I want `NULL` returned as the `format_code` which works fine in my query. The join to gen_codes would thus knock these ones off.

Comment: Also note that making the join to `gen_codes` a `left join` will not work either as a customer may appear on multiple lists that may not be related to the invoice format list.

Comment: could you please take a look at the modified query (i tried to describe what I intend to do with query, above it), when you get a chance? The basic idea is to prune the customer_list records using the account number filter.

Comment: Unfortunately this also does not work, this is due to my second comment that a customer may appear on multiple `customer_list`s with different `list_type`s. The `customer_list` is an ERP entity that is used to contain arbitrary lists of customers. Customers can exist on zero or many lists. Unfortunately the `gen_codes` link is required to identify the list type as an invoice format list type. There are several invoice format lists configured.